# do recursive templates producing runtime code?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, recursion

consider the following class:

```
class test {

  // recursively template 
  template<typename T, typename... R>
  void add(T t, R... r) {
    // do something with t
    if(sizeof...(r))
      add(r...);
  }
  // since the variadic template add is recursive, there have to be an end.
  void add() {}

public:

  template<typename... T>
  explicit test(T... rest) {
    add(rest...);
  }
};
```

and the following main:

```
int main() {
  test t1(1);
  test t2(1, 2);
  test t3(1, 2, 3);
}
```

*i shrunk down the code, so the `add` methods may not necessary.*

i think this code is **not** generating runtime recursion code, but creates 3 different constructors with 3 different number of parameters. am i right? i just want to make sure if i am right or not. if not what will happen then?

### edit:

the answers from **bames53** and **Casio Neri** are exact what i expected what is happening. however, it is not recursive but it still calling the the seperate add's like it would be one as you can see in bames53 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19665353/1810087). it's like semi-recursion.

Comment: Your above code is very likely optimized away completely, it's too simple to even understand why you are asking the question.

Comment: Are you asking whether the variadic expansion of the templates generates different implementations of `test()`? The answer is yes, and I'm somewhat lost as to what your definition of "runtime code" is if not referring to said-same expansions. Unrelated but noteworthy, you can mandate 1-or-more parameters by adding an additional `T` *specific* param to the constructor and the `add` methods. I only bring it up because of your comment on the no-op `add()` method.

Comment: @WhozCraig by runtime code i meant is the recursion also envolved at runtime. the answers from **bames53** and **Casio Neri** are exact what i expected what is happening. i was confused about the add method recursion. however, it is not recursive but it still calling the the seperate add's like it would be recursive.

Comment: @itwasntpete Those pretty-much spell out exactly what is happening with that expansion. Glad you found an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates generate regular classes and functions at compile time. Generated code, like constructors and functions, runs at runtime just like normal code.

Your program is essentially the same as if you'd written:

```
class test {
  void add(int t) {
    if(0)
      add();
  }

  void add(int t, int r) {
    if(1)
      add(r);
  }

  void add(int t, int r, int r2) {
    if(2)
      add(r, r2);
  }

  void add() {}

public:

  explicit test(int a) { add(a); }
  explicit test(int a, int b) { add(a, b); }
  explicit test(int a, int b, int c) { add(a, b, c); }
};

int main() {
  test t1(1);
  test t2(1, 2);
  test t3(1, 2, 3);
}
```

So effectively there is 'runtime' code just as if you'd written these normal functions, but it's also true that the template "creates 3 different constructors with 3 different number of parameters."

Templates do 'compile-time' computation by calculating what code to generate. This can be exploited to a much greater degree, often called 'template meta-programming'. The typical useless example:

```
template<int i>
struct fib {
  enum { value = fib<i-1>::value + fib<i-2>::value };
};

template<> struct fib<0> { enum { value = 1 }; };
template<> struct fib<1> { enum { value = 1 }; };

int main() {
  return fib<4>::value;
}
```

This is essentially the same as if I'd written:

```
struct fib_0 { enum { value = 1 }; };
struct fib_1 { enum { value = 1 }; };
struct fib_2 { enum { value = 2 }; };
struct fib_3 { enum { value = 3 }; };
struct fib_4 { enum { value = 5 }; };

int main() {
  return 5;
}
```

So, again, templates are just generating normal code. The compile time computation is in figuring out what code to generate.

Answer (score 2):

**All code in templates is generated at compile time.** That is the entire point of templates, variadic templates are no different, generally you do compile time recursion to get variadic templates to terminate. It is basically as if you had written the methods as nested. After the phase of the compiler where templates are expanded (not sure if this is exactly how it works, I'm not a compiler expert) it basically looks as if there had never been templates they are expanded out and turn into template instances, which are in essence no different than normal code. I would guess that generally the compiler will also inline most of the methods generated by variadic templates to produce more efficient code.

**EDIT:** keep in mind when I wrote this I decided to give you some credit and assume that your actual code does more than what you posted (which essentially does nothing)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in your case the compiler will generate 3 overloads of `test::add` and 3 overloads of `test::test` (taking 1, 2 and 3 arguments of type `int`).

To check that, compile the code (in file `main.cpp`) with gcc using options `-std=c++11 -c main.cpp`. This generates `main.o`. Then use `nm -C main.o` to check the symbols in the object file. You'll get (among other things)

```
00000000 T void test::add<int>(int)
00000000 T void test::add<int, int>(int, int)
00000000 T void test::add<int, int, int>(int, int, int)
00000000 T test::test<int>(int)
00000000 T test::test<int, int>(int, int)
00000000 T test::test<int, int, int>(int, int, int)
```

Where you can see all the mentioned overloads.

It's worth mentionning that gcc didn't create code for `test::add` that takes no argument (the non-template function) because it inlines the call. If you move the definition out of the class:

```
void test::add() {}
```

then gcc also generates this symbol and the output of `nm -C main.o` includes

```
00000000 T test::add()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there will be 3 different instances of `test` generated, and a bunch of `test::add` member function definitions for each invocation. But ultimately, your code is not doing anything, so it'll all be optimized away. [Here's the assembly output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de832fe3cd5ecffb) from g++4.8.1 with `-O3` enabled.

```
.file   "main.cpp"
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB3:
    .cfi_startproc
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE3:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.8.1"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I'm far from an expert on reading x86 assembly, but I think it's clear that all your code is being thrown away from the final executable.

Comment: additional: didn't know gcc will autogenerate a `return 0;`